# Maximum CPU Temperature for Core 2 Duo E6400

Tags: cpu, temperature, overclocking

What is considered to be the highest safe CPU temperature when overclocking?

I have a Core 2 Duo E6400 overclocked to 2.85GHz with 1.2vCore. This runs at 29C idle and 45C under load. These temperatures are captured using Speed Fan and PC Probe.

I know these temperatures are fine, but if I want to push it to over 3.0GHz what sort of maximum temperature limit should I set?

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[61.4 degrees centigrade.](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_2/Intel-Core%202%20Duo%20E6400%20HH80557PH0462M%20(BX80557E6400).html)  Of course, this leaves **zero** margin for safety, and your motherboard may or may not record temps in half-degree increments.  So I'd stick with 60 as a nice round number that happens to give you about 1.5-2 degrees of wiggle room.  This would be the maximum upper limit of what your CPU would handle, you'll be pushing the envelope of its design.

If you plan on keeping this overclocked forever and a day, I'd even consider something lower, so that the safety factor involved is larger, say 55 degrees.

And of course, this advice is given with the standard disclaimer that if you cook it by overclocking it, it was your decision, not mine; I'm not responsible for what you do; and you get to keep the burnt bits and pieces.

Comment: So 61.4 is really the upper limit to prevent the cpu burning out? Thought it'd be a bit higher.

Comment: typo noted, fixed.

Comment: I hate disclaimers like that.  But it's needed where I'm at.  That being said, good luck, and I hope you get it to a nice speed without cooking it!

Answer (score 4):

From [Intel's site](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=27249):

> **Package Specifications**
>   Thermal Specification   61.4°C