# CPU temperature between 39-58C, Is It normal?

Tags: cpu, temperature, intel-core2

I have an Intel Core 2 Duo E8400, this is the temperature information at light load:

[image]

And this is the temperature at heavy load:

[image]

Is this normal?

On one hand I have a SU user says that [this is not normal](https://superuser.com/questions/85410/cpu-fan-is-loud-but-the-temperature-is-ok-i-think), on the other there is an expectation that the idle temperature [should be around 50C](http://forums.techarena.in/overclocking-computer-modification/1273312.htm). Which one is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My work laptop has a Core 2 Duo and regularly gets up to 55C when working hard, I wouldn't consider it massively hot.

There's a temperature guide for Core 2 Processors [here](http://www.hardwareluxx.de/community/showthread.php?t=457229).  It does look rather confused, but hopefully it will make sense.

Answer (score 5):

Until your load temps get close to Tj. Max ([Temperature Junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_temperature) Max -- the maximum temperature Intel rates the processor for, beyond which it will throttle itself to cool down) there is absolutely nothing to worry about.

Since you're about 42 degrees away, even under load, I think you're quite safe...

Comment: Does it mean that for a mobile Core2 Duo (T_{case} = T_{junction} = 100 °C) the normal is 60 °C?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you're using CoreTemp, and it seems that CoreTemp reports higher [temps than actuals:](http://www.hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1290205)

> only with RealTemp the readings are 10
> degrees lower > 30-32C idle. I think
> the readings you're getting are
> normal, but the actual temp is lower.

---

> My temperatures are also ~10 degrees
> higher with Core Temp than Real Temp,
> and I'm hitting loads of about 50C
> with Core Temp on an Ultima-90 at
> 3.0GHz. Way too hot to be real.

---

Even if those were the real temperatures, they aren't that alarming, and as Jeff mentioned, Tj. max temperatures are still quite a bit off from your temperature readouts.

FWIW The Core2Duo T5250 on my Dell Inspiron 1520 hits ~ 47 idle, ~60 on load ~80-85 on gaming, and laptop's about 2 years now and I haven't faced any problems/

Answer (score 0):

No worries indeed. If you want to keep your temp that low, keep your system dust free, after a few months your systems temp will be hotter because of the dust that will stick on your ventilators and air ways.

Answer (score -1):

The normal temperature for a laptop is between 30 and 45 Celsius.
A hard disk temp of 47 Celsius is okay, but if more than that, you should replace the thermal paste and clean dust from the processor fan.