# Is this a normal temperature for my laptop?

Tags: laptop, temperature

I'm using Acer Aspire E15, the average I get is between 40-50°C on my CPU when I'm not playing games and 50-60°C when I am, is that normal? It's not shutting down, It's 1 year old , I don't really know if there is a requirement like that, It's not really uncomfortable and I haven't cleaned the vents in a while, but not that long. I'm just paranoid if it is overheating, my last laptop died like that.

Here's a Core Temp screenshot if it helps:

[image: Core Temp 1.0 RC6]

Comment: 50-60 what?  Unless your laptop is shutting down then it isn't overheating

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CPU temperature between 39-58C, Is It Normal?](http://superuser.com/questions/85671/cpu-temperature-between-39-58c-is-it-normal)

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following:

1. As Ramhound already asked if it is shutting down?
2. Is it uncomfortable?
3. Is it a requirement to be colder because you're using it in an environment where that heat is not allowed?
4. The age of the laptop
5. Are the vents clean (don't use it on surfaces where it can breathe the hot air out e.g Bed or sofa)

To answer I will ad some links to some testing done on laptops, specifically the Acer Aspire E15.

1. [States normal temperatures of 33 Celcius, but when stressed 55 Celcius](http://laptopmedia.com/review/acer-aspire-e15-e5-573-review-with-emphasis-on-the-keyboard-touchpad-and-design/)
2. [Explains the case temperature remains under the 40 Celcius during stress test](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Acer-Aspire-E15-ES1-511-C50C-Notebook-Review-Update.129058.0.html)

So link 1 tells us you're a bit higher (but don't forget the first questions, take them into consideration). And link 2 tells us your much higher.

**But keep in mind:**

1. Where did you measure (in the links you can see, different area's have different temperatures)?
2. Did you also measure Celcius (please update your question)

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop should and will have measures to shutdown and warn you automatically when it gets too hot to use. You dont need to worry about it.

Where are you getting the values from? (Which sensor, CPU, FAN, GPU?)

What is the ambient room temperature where you are operating the device? is it hot? If it is at 20-25 degree level then 40-50 degree might be a bit hot but nothing to worry about. 50-60 degree under load is normal for most laptops.