# Low CPU usage but High fan speed

Tags: cpu, fan, noise

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CPU Fan is Loud, but the Temperature is OK (I Think)](https://superuser.com/questions/85410/cpu-fan-is-loud-but-the-temperature-is-ok-i-think)

The problem I am facing is the CPU fan rotates with high speed even though the CPU usage is very low, less than 10%.

I even cleaned the Dust off the Fan, I replaced the Thermal Material on the Processor. Installed an Extra Fan.

Nothing seems to Work.

Please Help.

Comment: You mention "Speedfan" as a tag - what's that reporting as to your CPU temps?

Comment: @Phoshi - maybe he didn't know it was an application. Just thought it was a tag for "fan speed".

Comment: Even though this may seem to be a h/w problem, it would be nice to know the O/S. Even different generations of Windows have different abilities to interact with the hardware. Also, what kind of system or motherboard do you have? If Windows, are there chipset drivers and are they loaded? Running an nVidia or ATi chipset without drivers will lead to many issues.

Comment: Is this a new problem for this computer?  That is, did the fan slow down under low CPU load in the past?

Answer (score 1):

Some mainboards/BIOSes come with faulty ACPI tables that might cause the fan to turn on too early or too late. On older operating systems this sometimes wasn't so much of a problem but newer ones more closely honor the settings there and as a result might lead to what you describe. You might want to check whether a BIOS update solves the problem.

There are also power settings in your operating system which might prevent the CPU from entering a lower power state (for example if it's forced to always run at full clock speed). You may want to check there, too.

Comment: thanx.. ill just check that