# What is the maximum temperature my CPUs can reach before causing damage?

Tags: cpu, fan, temperature

After my [BIOS reset itself](https://superuser.com/questions/202702/why-would-my-computer-all-of-sudden-reset-clock-show-new-boot-screen-and-run-fa) for some reason, my computer/cpu **fan is running non-stop**, so I installed [speedfan](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php) so I can monitor the temperature of the four cores I have.

I was alarmed to see three "**flaming fire icons**" and assumed these cores were too hot but after some research [here](https://superuser.com/questions/7153/maximum-cpu-temperature) and [here](http://www.technibble.com/what-is-my-computers-maximum-cpu-temperature/), it seems that maximum CPU temperatures are 60C - 70C and that **50C - 52C** is still quite normal.

[image]

Here's the basic info about my computer hardware:

- Asus P5QL Pro Sockel 775 Intel P43 max. 8GB DDR2-1066 ATX
- Intel Core2 Quad Q9300 Sockel 775 2.5 GHz FSB 1333 MHz Boxed 2x3MB L2 Cach 95W Yorkfield
- 2x Team Group TVDD2048M800C5 2038MB (2GB) DIMM DDR2-800 / PC2-6400 CL5 184pin Non-ECC
- Arctic Cooling Freezer 7 Pro CPU-Cooler Socket 775
- BE Quiet System Power BQT S6-SYS-UA-450W Netzteil 450Watt
- BE Quiet SilentWings BQT-T9225-LF Case Fan 92mm 16 dBA 32.6 CFM 1800rpm

**Can anyone assure me that as long as the temperature of my cores stays below 55C they will be alright?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Intel](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=33922&processor=Q9300&spec-codes=SLAWE) your processor `Tcase`**<sup>(*)</sup>** should be fine at temps up to  71.4°C

(*)
Tcase temperature is measured at the IHS or that metal casing protecting the core on your processor, which is what your BIOS will report. Core or Tjunction temperatures will show a higher temp.

Answer (score 1):

My iMac Core2Duo T7700 2.4GHz is currently running both cores at 100% (H.264 encoding) and they both read 72°C. Fans are quiet (as usual on this system) and everything's smooth.

This system is three years old and more often than not spends one or two days encoding lots of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

below 55oC is good for your CPUs.

Intel CPU can deal with 80*C in 7,8 hrs I think . . .

Higher temp, your mobo will turn off your PC immediately so don't worry :)